# How to get array length of JSON in robot framework

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

I'm using this code and the first line works fine. I think I'm getting the wrong array for this:

```
${json_object}    evaluate        json.loads('''${sn_booking_payload}''' , strict=False)    json
${answers_count}    Get Length    ${json_object["$.preBookAnswers.answers[0]"]}
```

it returns this error:

```
Resolving variable '${json_object["$.preBookAnswers.answers[0]"]}' failed: KeyError: '$.preBookAnswers.answers[0]'
```

this is the JSON snippet. I'm trying to get  the length of index of answers.

```
"preBookAnswers": {
    "answers": [
                    {
                        "entityId": "2bfd67b0-a315-4dd1-b3e1-ce1d417e9cf9",
                        "userInput": "",
                        "itemIds": [],
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "item": "Customer Meeting",
                                "value": "",
                                "description": ""
                            }
                        ],
                        "customFieldType": "QUESTION",
                        "questionDisplayText": "Reason for Travel"
                    },
                    {
                        "entityId": "ec376e47-b7d7-47f5-811d-90430eae02f8",
                        "userInput": "",
                        "itemIds": [],
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "item": "J123",
                                "value": "",
                                "description": ""
                            }
                        ],
                        "customFieldType": "QUESTION",
                        "questionDisplayText": "DP Code"
                    }
    ],
    "preBookQuestionResponseId": ""
}
```

I tried playing around with the value of the `json_object`.

Comment: In addition to perfect Pekka answer, I just want to highlight why your example didn't work.
The result of `json.load` is common dictionary, not JSON object. So it should accessed in usual dictionary way. E.g. 
`get length  ${json_object}[preBookAnswers]`. Or use not dict but JSON object as in Pekka answer.

Comment: And one more minor comment just in case. You could get rid of so many quotes in the first line of your code. It could be  `${json_object}    evaluate        json.loads($sn_booking_payload , strict=False)    json`

Comment: My apologize for my error in the first comment: `get length  ${json_object}[preBookAnswers]`
should be `get length  ${json_object}[preBookAnswers][answers][0][answers]` if you want to count answers for the first question in your json (e.g. with `entityId=2bfd67b0`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse a JSON with $, you should use library like `jsonpath_ng`. This is one case where it might be beneficial to write a new keyword with Python. Something like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library                     JsonSearch.py

*** Test Cases ***
search
    ${sn_booking_payload}=    Catenate  SEPARATOR=
...    {
...    "preBookAnswers": {
...    "answers": [
...                    {
...                        "entityId": "2bfd67b0-a315-4dd1-b3e1-ce1d417e9cf9",
...                        "userInput": "",
...                        "itemIds": [],
...                        "answers": [
...                            {
...                                "item": "Customer Meeting",
...                                "value": "",
...                                "description": ""
...                            }
...                        ],
...                        "customFieldType": "QUESTION",
...                        "questionDisplayText": "Reason for Travel"
...                    },
...                    {
...                        "entityId": "ec376e47-b7d7-47f5-811d-90430eae02f8",
...                        "userInput": "",
...                        "itemIds": [],
...                        "answers": [
...                            {
...                                "item": "J123",
...                                "value": "",
...                                "description": ""
...                            }
...                        ],
...                        "customFieldType": "QUESTION",
...                        "questionDisplayText": "DP Code"
...                    }
...    ],
...    "preBookQuestionResponseId": ""
...    }
...    }
    ${json_object}=    Evaluate        json.loads('''${sn_booking_payload}''' , strict=False)    json
    ${answers_count}=    CountAnswers    ${json_object}    $.preBookAnswers.answers[0]
    Should Be Equal As Numbers    ${answers_count}    1
```

Keyword would look like this:

```
from jsonpath_ng import parse

from robot.api.deco import keyword


@keyword("Count Answers")
def count_answers(json_object: dict, parse_str: str) -> int:
    jsonpath_expr = parse(parse_str)
    return len(jsonpath_expr.find(json_object))
```