# Robot Framework parsing JSON

Tags: json, robotframework

I have this json where I need to extract second item, but I only know the first value(nickname = BigApple). So is it possible fetch value of city some how using knowledge of nickname? This is only part of JSON.

```
{
  "Items":[
  {
   "data":{
   "nickname":"BigApple",
   "city":"New York",
   "country":"USA"
   },...
```

Comment: it is not quite clear from the question what data format exactly you have. I mean your example could be a really JSON object from 3d party lib or common python dict actually (as usual), etc. Please, give a piece of code where you get it.  Some hints could be found in answer and comment, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77199222/how-to-get-array-length-of-json-in-robot-framework)

Comment: There are no cool one liners for getting that. Unless your json is huge, I would write a simple loop that goes through all items and fetches city when nickname is correct.

Comment: ${res}=  Get Value from json ${your json}  jsonpath.   You can use json query . More info: https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2